# Hortonworks-oozie

Tags: workflow, hive, oozie

I am trying to run a workflow in hortonworks cluster using oozie.
Getting the following error:

**Error: Invalid workflow-app, org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'hive'.**

does anyone know the reason?
Atleast a sample hive workflow.xml which can be run on hortonworks distribution would be helpful??

Comment: Have you posted this on the Hortonworks Oozie forum? They're usually really good at getting back to you in a timely manner. http://hortonworks.com/community/forums/forum/sqoop-oozie/

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the first line of your workflow:

```
<workflow-app name="${workflowName}" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4">
```

Specifically: *uri:oozie:workflow:0.4*

the xmlns value tells oozie what xml pattern to follow. I am assuming you used an online resource to build an action, which maybe in a newer scheme than what you specified.

There are versions

*-uri:oozie:workflow:0.1*

*-uri:oozie:workflow:0.2*

*-uri:oozie:workflow:0.2.5*

*-uri:oozie:workflow:0.3*

*-uri:oozie:workflow:0.4*

See: [Oozie Workflow Schemes](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#OozieWFSchema)

But Usually setting yours to the code example above (0.4) will work for all newer workflows.

---

Actions also have schemes so it is important to look at what functions they have in each version.

The hive action currently goes up to 0.5 I believe, although I use 0.4 with this line:

```
<hive xmlns="uri:oozie:hive-action:0.4">
```

If this does not help, please update the question with your workflow for further help.